# Finding $c_0$ in Complex form of Fourier Series of $x^2$ where $0\le x\le 2\pi$

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-series

> $f(x)=x^2\qquad\qquad 0\le x\le 2\pi\qquad\qquad T=2\pi$

I was watching a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsz4ZuYR7iA) about complex form of Fourier Series. For this problem (I wrote exactly what was presented in the video) the teacher said we first find $c_0$ from the formula $$c_n=\frac{1}{2l}\int_{-l}^{l} f(x)e^{\tfrac{-in\pi  x}l}$$
And said since $f(x)$ is periodic function it doesn't matter if you integrate over $[-\pi,\pi]$ or $[0,2\pi]$. Then he evaluated $$c_0=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} x^2 dx$$
But I think this is wrong, since from the graph of $y=x^2$ we can intuitively see the area under the curve for $x\in[0,2\pi]$ is more than area for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$.

Hence I think according the formula, the correct integral should be $$c_0=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^2 dx$$Am I right?

Comment: I just added link of the video (although it is in Persian but it may be helpful).

Comment: The periodic version of $f(x)=x^2$ is different depending on how you define the interval. The author's evaluation limits are correct since the periodic function $f(x)$ is defined on the interval $0\le x\le 2\pi$. The periodic function $f(x)$ defined on the interval $-\pi\le x\le \pi$ is not equivalent.

Comment: @StevenClark Thanks a lot! It is clear now.